# <rich:calendar> does not popup on click

Tags: jsf, richfaces

JSF 2.2
Richfaces 4.3.3
Java 7
Netbeans 7.3.1

Im trying to use a richfaces popup calender, but it does not popup, i can see the input field aswell as the calender icon but when i click it nothing happens. when setting popup to false i can see the whole calender.

Page examples:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">



<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml" >
        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailTitle}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="pagetitle">
            <h:outputText value="Client Details" styleClass="auto-style3"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="heads">
            <h:link outcome="/login/admin.xhtml" value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailIndexLink}"/>
        </ui:define>





<ui:define name="body">
            <!-- CLIENT INFORMATION-->
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingLabel_employeesEmployeeNo}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{employeesController.getEmployees(timeLoggingController.selected.employeesEmployeeNo).name} #{employeesController.getEmployees(timeLoggingController.selected.employeesEmployeeNo).surname}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingTitle_employeesEmployeeNo}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingLabel_customersId}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{customersController.getCustomers(timeLoggingController.selected.customersId).name}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingTitle_customersId}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingLabel_projectsId}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{projectsController.getProjects(timeLoggingController.selected.projectsId).description}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingTitle_projectsId}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingLabel_tasksId}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{tasksController.getTasks(timeLoggingController.selected.tasksId).description}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingTitle_tasksId}"/>
                    <br/>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:outputText value="Log Time" styleClass="auto-style3" />
                <!-- LOG TIME PANEL-->
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <table border="1" style="text-align: center" class="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row, jsfcrud_list_form">
                    <tr>
                        <th><h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailLabel_date}" for="date" /></th>
                        <th><h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailLabel_description}" for="description" /></th>
                        <th><h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailLabel_normalHours}" for="normalHours" /></th>
                        <th><h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailLabel_overtimeHours}" for="overtimeHours" /></th>
                        <th><h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailLabel_doubleTimeHours}" for="doubleTimeHours" /></th>
                        <th><h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailLabel_billTypesId}" for="billTypesId" /></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <rich:calendar value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.date}" locale="Locale.US" popup="true" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"  style="width:200px"/>
                        </td>
                        <td><h:inputText id="description" value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.description}" title="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailTitle_description}" size="18" /></td>
                        <td><h:inputText id="normalHours" value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.normalHours}" title="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailTitle_normalHours}"  size="10"/></td>
                        <td><h:inputText id="overtimeHours" value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.overtimeHours}" title="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailTitle_overtimeHours}" size="10" /></td>
                        <td><h:inputText id="doubleTimeHours" value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.doubleTimeHours}" title="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailTitle_doubleTimeHours}" size="16" /></td>
                        <td><h:selectOneMenu id="billTypesId" value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.billTypesId}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{billTypesController.items}" var="i" itemLabel="#{i.description}" itemValue="#{i.id}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu></td>
                        <td> <h:commandLink onclick="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.timeLoggingId=timeLoggingController.selected.id}" action="#{timeLoggingDetailController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailSaveLink}" styleClass="linkbutton"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br/>
            </h:form>
```

where i use the calender:

```
<rich:calendar value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.date}" locale="Locale.US" popup="true" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"  style="width:200px"/>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>plain</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

I also have `<h:head></h:head>` in my template file

Comment: Any errors in the JS console? Does it work outside the table?

Comment: no errors, not working outside table

Comment: If you inspect the HTML is the popup in there? There might be some CSS rules blocking it from view. Or the click is not reaching the Javascript. There is nothing wrong with your code as far as I can tell. One more thing - is the page included dynamically or statically?

Comment: Hi, When I inspect the html the popup is there, im not sure how the css rules can block it? my css atm is only used for the way i display my datatables and buttons. the page is static. kind regards

Comment: The popup is a table, if you try it without your CSS and see the popup then you'll know CSS is the issue.

Comment: Oky tried without my css and still no popup, if i set the popup to false it displays the whole calender, when i set popup to true it shows the inputfield with a small button next to it to make calender popup but when clicked still nothing.

Comment: hi, issue was resolved.

<script src="test.js"></script>

changed to:

<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

and problem was resolved.